# Python array loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to solve the below. First part i am able to do, but its the second part of the question where I need to create a loop, that checks until the values in array are greater than 100, it will keep on multiplying by 2 and print the result.

Use a mask to multiply all values below 100 in the following list by

```
a = np.array([30, 10, 84, 101, 76])
```

Repeat this until all values are above 100. (Not manually, but by looping):

I think the best is to use While loop, but I am unable to use it.

Comment: Unless you explain how exactly you are "unable" to use it, I'm afraid we are unable to help you.

Answer (score 0):

No loops or masks are necessary as the number of multiplications required can be calculated explicitly; in particular,

```
a * 2**np.floor(np.log2(100/a) + 1)
```

does what you want.

Comment: Very interesting approach, but I'm afraid what he wants is the values of the array, not the number of operations. His problem is super easy, so I'm not going to post the answer until he tries something himself. This looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

See, this is what I have, It might be super simple to many, but to a novice like me, it was not. I had prob with with 'while'

```
a = [230, 10, 284, 39, 76]
```

x =1
y=1
while True:
if x!=0:
       print(a)
       for i in range(len(a)):
           if a[i]<100:
               a[i]=a[i]*2
               y=0
           i+=1
           if (i==len(a) and y==1):
               x=0
               break
       y=1
    else:
           break

Comment: ps. i am also not sure how to post a code here. But, this is something i am trying to figure out. it was not a homework question.